# How to create arrow symbol inbetween and adjust <<>> in Enterprise Architect from Sparx Systems

Tags: uml, enterprise-architect

I'd like to create following connection

[image]

but I'not able to find the connection in the tool `Enterprise Architect 16.1` from `Sparx Systems`, that the black arrow symbol is in between the beginning and end and also to add the custom made `<<digital input>>`.

[image]

Is this an "official" UML connection? Where to find this in the tool?

**Update** It's getting closer (thanks to @Geert Bellekens)

[image]

Comment: I would suggest to use the singular form "speedometer pulse". At any given time I would expect at most one pulse to be on the way. 

Also, I would not use an InformationItem here. While it seems to be appropriate to use an InformationItem with an InformationFlow, it is also allowed to use any classifier here. Given your example, I would use a Signal.

Comment: You use a stereotype «digital input». I guess, that means that the speedometer pulses _are_ digital inputs. Then maybe a digital signal is the thing that actually _is flowing_. Since we know, that the digital signals are coming from a speedometer, we will _interpret_ them as speedometer pulses. But that is nothing that is inherent in the _type_ of the signal. If we connect the speedometer to an input where the system expects depth signals, it will happily calculate a meaningless depth. Therefore, the Signal `speedometer pulse` is not existing. It's just a `digital signal`.

Comment: @AxelScheithauer I'd like to highlight, that I copied the first picture (so I'm not able to modify or access this example) and the question is not about how reasonable the diagram is. I just wanted to reproduce the "technique" in the diagram. I will try to play around with your suggestions.

Comment: Enterprise Architect allows you to quickly add a new stereotype. Just click the three dots in the stereotype field of the association. However, stereotypes should be carefully planned. You should define them in a profile and then use it in multiple projects.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is something like an association, or CommunicationPath with an information flow realized.

Right click on your association and choose **Advanced | Information Flows Realized...**
[image]

In this case the conveyed element is probably the **speedometer pulses**

The `«ditigal input»` you see on the diagram is a stereotype. It might be part of an MDG, or simply a custom stereotype, but that is impossible to say from an image.

You can create your own stereotype for the connector by clicking the [...] button in the properties next to **Stereotype**
[image]

Comment: I think it cannot be an associaton, because they cannot be connected to a port. It must be a connector. Therefore, it should be a composite structure diagram, making it necessary to show colons in front of the types (e.g. `:speedometer`).

Comment: I think communicationPath could be possible as well (has the same look) but since it has a stereotype, it also might be something completely different defined in some UML profile.

Comment: A CommunicationPath is a special Association. So the same rules apply here. Even Enterprise Architect now enforces this rule - for Associations. Apparently they have forgotten CommunicationPaths. That's what you get, when the tool is clueless about the metamodel. A stereotype doesn't help. Which element notated with a solid line could be the base of such a stereotype? As far as I can see the only candidates are Association, CommunicationPath, Connector and Link (not to be confused with what EA calls a link).

Comment: @AxelScheithauer If I would define my own stereotype, then I'm in control of what's legal or not, and how it look in a diagram. A stereotype is effectively a new metatype, with new rules. (It's no longer UML, so the rules of UML don't apply)

Comment: I agree that a stereotype is a new metatype, albeit with limited possibilities, hence _stereo_ type. That means it can _add_ new rules, but cannot _change_ the existing rules of the base UML-element. It can also _add_ an icon, but it cannot _change_ the shape or the style of the lines. It is possible that some tools allow to do this. There is, however, no standard mechanism for this purpose, as far as I can see.

Comment: @AxelScheithauer I'm not sure about that. Have you looked at the UML profile for BPMN published by the OMG? https://www.omg.org/spec/BPMNProfile/1.0/About-BPMNProfile#document-metadata We can hardly argue that BPMN doesn't change shapes or linestyles can we?

Comment: Well, _"This specification enables modelers to use BPMN 2 process and collaboration notation as a concrete syntax for UML activity and collaboration models."_ 

I think that means a tool can save a BPMN diagram as a UML-model with the BPMN profile applied and this model has the same semantics as the BPMN-model. It doesn't mean that opening this model with a UML tool will look like BPMN. For this to happen UML profiles would need a mechanism to change the notation. Stereotypes can define an icon, but that's about it. A tool vendor can build in support for BPMN notation, but not a tool user.